# Mediation in R Package lavaan: Total effect of the IV has a different p-value than the same variable in a Multiple Regression

Tags: regression, r, p-value, mediation, lavaan

I am really confused with the results of my mediation analysis using `lavaan`. I am using one predictor and several covariates. Is there any reason why `lavaan` would give me "wrong" $p$-values?

Here's how I specified my model (using easy variable names):

```
D.Model <- '
  Y ~ cp * IV + cov1 + cov2 
  M ~ a * IV + cov1 + cov2 
  Y ~ b * M
  ab := a * b
  total := cp + (a * b)
      '

fit.D <- sem(model = D.Model, data = data_complete, 
             estimator = "ML", 
             se= "boot", bootstrap = 5000)
```

Lavaan gives me a total effect of $.103$ and a $p$-value of $.016$. As far as I see it, this means that the IV has an effect on $Y$ without considering the mediator variable. I also ran a regression analysis in order to validate my results:

```
reg.D <- lm(Y ~ IV + cov1 + cov2)
summary(reg.D)
```

Here, I get the same estimate as a regression coefficient of the IV. ($.103$). However, the $p$-value is $.052$, rendering it not significant. (I did a couple of other computations, the $p$-values also differ in a large extent from the results in the multiple regression).

I reran the analysis using the PROCESS macro for SPSS - here, the $p$-values of the total effect in the mediation analysis and the $p$-value of the regression coefficient are identical (not only close, but identical).

Answer (score 1):

Structural equation modeling and linear regression are related, but different, analyses. If I had to guess here, `lavaan` is allowing variables to be measured with error by default even though you're specify regression-type models. An assumption of linear regression models, like those used for the PROCESS macro, is that all variables are measured without error. Structural equation modeling, on the other hand, extends the analysis of covariance matrices to estimate error within variables. The difference in your results may very well be that one model assumes no measurement error (PROCESS macro running OLS regression) while the other one estimates error in the variables (`lavaan`). A potential check for this being the explanation would be to look at whether the lavaan model is returning estimates for the errors of each variable.

Comment: Thanks, Billy!

I already thought about that being the source of the difference, but I could now validate it using the "psych"package. The command mediate() uses the OLS-approach and perfectly replicates the results from PROCESS. :)

Comment: @eventually, glad you were able to figure this out! I'm not sure which method you're planning on taking, but I would suggest the SEM estimation since the OLS regression assumption of no measurement error is usually untenable

Comment: yes, I know. Actually I am performing OLS and SEM estimation - part of my work is to compare old and new approaches to analysis in my field. Thanks and have a great week!

Answer (score 0):

In the lavaan package, you have successfully defined and performed the Baron and Kenny test of mediation. Somehow you seem to implement that in the lavaan code snippet without realizing it - there is no SEM happening, you are using lavaan as a fancy way to fit OLS models. In the OLS regression model, you have simply included the variable as a predictor in the analysis. As a reminder, if a variable $M$ is a mediator of the $X$ and $Y$ relationship, then $X$ is causal of $M$ and $M$ is causal of $Y$, with the mediation effect defined as the product of the path weights. In OLS modeling, you fit two models;

$$E[M|X] = \alpha_0 + \beta_0 X$$
$$E[Y|M,X] = \alpha_1 + \beta_1 M + \gamma X$$

The mediation effect is $\beta_0 \beta_1$ and the standard error of the term is $\sqrt{\beta_0^2 SE(\beta_1)^2 + \beta_1 SE(\beta_0)^2 + SE(\beta_0)^2 SE(\beta_1)^2}$ which approximates normal in adequate sample sizes. Extending this for a bootstrap based statistical inference is a trivial exercise. In short, if you're going to compare SEM and OLS, you have to realize what they're doing!

[https://play.psych.mun.ca/~jcarter/6602/Psych%206602%20Winter%202014/Baron%20&%20Kenny%201986.pdf](https://play.psych.mun.ca/%7Ejcarter/6602/Psych%206602%20Winter%202014/Baron%20&%20Kenny%201986.pdf)